# (Generalized) Uncentered Maximal Function $\tilde Mf$ in Stein's Harmonic Analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

It is well known that on $\Bbb R^n$, equipped with the usual Lebesgue measure, the standard Hardy-Littlewood maximal function $Mf(x)$ (with respect to averaging on cubes or balls centered at $x$) is essentially equivalent to the uncentered version $\tilde Mf(x)$. In Stein's Harmonic Analysis, the same claim is made for a generalized version of the maximal functions, where the "balls" are only required to satisfy some considerably weak assumptions. However, it is not clear to me how to prove the claim.

I asked the same question [here on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206598/generalized-uncentered-maximal-function-tilde-mf-in-steins-harmonic-analys) over a week ago but so far there has been no reply.

---

Let me first write down all the definitions from Stein's book. Let $\mu$ be a fixed Borel measure on $\Bbb R^n$. For each $x\in \Bbb R^n$, a family of *balls* $\{B(x,\delta)\}_{\delta>0}$ is associated. Each ball is defined to be a bounded, open set such that the family is monotone in the sense that $B(x,\delta_1)\subset B(x,\delta_2)$ whenever $\delta_1<\delta_2$. It is also postulated that $\cup_{\delta>0} B(x,\delta) = \Bbb R^n$ and $\cap_{\delta>0} B(x,\delta) = \{x\}$. The relationship between balls with different centers is given by

> There exists $c_1>1$ such that for any $x,y \in\Bbb R^n$ and $\delta>0$, we have
> $$
> B(x,\delta) \cap B(y,\delta) \ne \emptyset  \implies B(y,\delta) \subset B(x,c_1\delta).
> $$
> Moreover, for the same $c_1$ as above, there exists $c_2>1$ such that for any $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $\delta>0$,
> $$
> \mu(B(x,c_1\delta)) \le c_2 \mu(B(x,\delta)).
> $$

Now, for any $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb R^n, d\mu)$, the *maximal function* $Mf$ is defined with respect to such a family of "balls", i.e.
$$
Mf(x) := \sup_{\delta>0} \frac{1}{\mu(B(x,\delta))} \int_{B(x,\delta)} |f| \,d\mu
$$
whereas the *uncentered maximal function* $\tilde Mf$ is defined analogously, i.e.
$$
\tilde Mf(x) := \sup \left\{ \frac{1}{\mu(B(y,\delta))} \int_{B(y,\delta)} |f| \,d\mu \ :\ x \in B(y,\delta) \right\}.
$$

---

It is not hard to prove that  there exists $C>0$ such that
$$
\tilde Mf \le C \cdot Mf
$$
under the above assumptions, hence the 2 versions of maximal functions are equivalent. However, it is claimed in the book (without a proof) that this inequality holds under an even weaker assumption on the relationship between $B(x,\delta), B(y,\delta)$. Instead of postulating the existence of $c_1,c_2>1$ as above we instead assume

> For each $B(x,\delta)$, we define $B^*(x,\delta)$ to be the set
> $$
> B^*(x,\delta) := \bigcup \left\{ B(y,\delta) : B(x,\delta) \cap B(y,\delta) \ne \emptyset \right\}.
> $$
> There exists $c_3>1$ such that
> $$
> \mu(B^*(x,\delta)) \le c_3\mu(B(x,\delta)).
> $$

Under this weaker assumption, I can't see how to deduce the inequality $\tilde Mf \le C \cdot Mf$. For any $B(y,\delta)$ containing $x$, $B(y,\delta) \subset B^*(x,\delta)$ so we have the inequality
$$
\frac{1}{\mu(B(y,\delta))} \int_{B(y,\delta)} |f| \,d\mu \le \frac{\mu(B^*(x,\delta))}{\mu(B(y,\delta))} \cdot \frac{1}{\mu(B^*(x,\delta))} \int_{B^*(x,\delta)} |f| \,d\mu
$$
but since $B^*(x,\delta)$ does not belong to the family of "balls" $\{B(x,\delta)\}_{\delta>0}$, I'm not sure how to bound the averaging integral on the righthand-side (the ratio $\frac{\mu(B^*(x,\delta))}{\mu(B(y,\delta))}$ can be bounded by $(c_3)^2$ though).

Maybe I'm not seeing something obvious here? Could anyone help me figure out what did I miss? The book stated as if the statement is obvious but I can't seem to see why.